# Buttons Not Clickable in Flutter Parallax Scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I am trying to build Parallax Effect in my app, Most of the people suggest using `Stack` + `Positioned` + Any Scrollable widget in my case `ListView`.
So the issue is that due to `Stack` widget my buttons are not clickable as the transparent `ListView` widget is always on top of them.
Here's my pen:
https://codepen.io/sukhcha_in/pen/JjKYJpd 
Please suggest some better way of doing it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Not sure if this is the best solution but kinda works :P
Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/sukhcha_in/full/JjKYJpd

```
double myChildSize = 500.0;
double appbarHeight = appBar.preferredSize.height;
```